# how to clear database in Phonegap?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

i am using phonegap for android application in which i am using database to keep records by

```
var db = window.openDatabase("buildingdb", "1.0", "buildingdatabase", 4 * 1024 * 1024);

 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO........");
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO........");
```

i am inserting row datas using tx.executesql() ,before i was using 100 datas now i have reduced it to 2 datas but its showing all 100 datas.how could i clear database so it shows only what i have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the:

```
tx.executeSql("delete * from your_table_name")
```

Either temporary put the line in your code and run the app once. Either connect to the device using Chrome Inspector and run it from there, while you will need to access the `tx` somehow in that case.

Comment: "*" is not necessary on delete query